# Strange behaviour of a type assert

Tags: julia

For simplicity's sake, suppose I have the following function defined:

```
function returnVectorOrMatrix()
    vals = Array(Array{Float32,1}, 10)   # vector in this definition
    return vals::Array{Array{Float32},1}
end

arr = returnVectorOrMatrix()
```

Which to my big surprise generates the following error:

```
ERROR: type: typeassert: expected Array{Array{Float32,N},1},
got Array{Array{Float32,1},1}
```

Does anyone have a good logical reasoning as to why this is happening / was designed in such way?
Because `Array{Array{Float32,1},1}` is just a special case of `Array{Array{Float32,N},1}` with `N = 1` so given that `Julia` is multiple-dispatch I would expect such function to work fine (and seems logical/intuitive as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

```
julia> Array{Float32,1} <: Array{Float32}
true

julia> Array{Array{Float32,1},1} <: Array{Array{Float32},1}
false

julia> Array{Array{Float32,1},1} <: Array{Array{Float32,1}}
true
```

could you find any clue now?

in fact, the `Array{Array{Float32,1},1}` is a [parametric type](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/types/#man-parametric-types),

```
julia> Array{Array{Float32,1},1} <: Array{Array{Float32},1}
false
```

I think the mechanism here is the same case as:

```
julia> Array{Int32,1} <: Array{Int,1}
false
```

even if `Int32` is a special case of `Int`, julia will return a false here.

> Bacause Array{Array{Float32,1},1} is just a special case of Array{Array{Float32,N},1} with N = 1

so this statement is not true because `Array{Float32,1}` and `Array{Float32,N}` are type parameters which are invariant in julia.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is simply that Array{Float32} is really Array{Float32,N}, and not Array{Float32,1} (which is the same as Vector{Float32}).